# Is a "Poincaré map" of a second order ODE continuous?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, continuity

Given that $\phi_{c,\lambda}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is defined as:

> $\phi_{c,\lambda}(t)=y(\lambda)$ such that $y$ is the solution of:
>
> $
>  y'' = f(x, y, y') \\
>  y(0) = c\\
>  y'(0) = t
> $
>
> For some fixed $f$ locally Lipschitz in $y$ and $y'$

Is $\phi_{c,\lambda}\in C(\mathbb{R})$? Why? As far as I know, it should be.

If it isn't under the condition I give, but is under slightly stricter but conditions (e.g. $f$ being continuous in $x$) then it would also answer my question.

Comment: Do you mean $y''(\lambda) = f(x, y(\lambda), y'(\lambda))$?

Comment: @ArcticChar No, I meant $\forall_x y''(x) = f(x, y(x), y'(x))$